# how to stream video in asp.net core web API on Android?

Tags: android, asp.net-core, filestream, asp.net-core-webapi, sqlfilestream

How can I implement api with c# filestream or sql filestream in asp.net core to show video on Android?

1. Has a good speed
2. Secure
3. And optimal server resources

I use the jwt token for Android app communication and asp.net core api

Please introduce an article or some code samples and give me advice

Is using hls or signalR or RTSP and ... is there a better offer?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of videos are planing on streaming? average duration, quality, live streaming?

Comment: Any video
Such as youtube or instagram

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look to Microsoft SignalR? It´s pretty easy to develop and implement:

Server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Client (Java):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2

More info about SignalR:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/real-time

Regards.

Comment: In research I have noticed that signalR is not suitable for streaming video!

Comment: Check this out: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/video-streaming-with-asp-net-signalr-and-html5

Answer (score 0):

We have a simplified video streaming method working over SignalR Core.
Our open source academic project is at:
https://github.com/manukautech/XMRemoteRobot

Web app. Sender page uses <video> and <canvas> html controls working together to capture 6 still images per second and send them as base64 text. That way the image is part of the robot-monitoring telemetry signal. A SignalR signal is limited to 32000 characters which effectively limits image size to 240px x 400px. Obviously a modest workaround but in practice it works very well and stays reliable under challenging connection conditions e.g. video from a 3G mobile phone flying in a rocket.